# Descargar audios desde Firebase (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, firebase, descarga, audio

Hola gente de StackOverflow.

Soy alumno de un curso de Android y en clases comenzamos a ver como trabajar con Firebase. 
El caso es que he conseguido que mi aplicación reproduzca una serie de audios en mp3 desde la base de datos, pero ahora me gustaría compartirlo en otra aplicación, para ello, he hecho esto:

```
this.stRef  = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("audios/nombredelaudio.mp3");


File localFile = null;


try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("nombreaudio", ".mp3");
        audiotempdescargado = localFile.getPath();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

stRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"creado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"fallo al crear"+exception,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Hasta aquí más o menos bien, he podido comprobar que la app descarga un archivo temporal explorando desde Android Studio, pero cuando lo pasas a otra aplicación con este método, no traslada nada:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(audiotempdescargado);
Intent share =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND,uri);
share.setType("audio/*");
c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Compartir sonido en: "));
```

}

He seguido las indicaciones que da la propia guía de Firebase para descargar archivos, pero no consigo tener éxito([link](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/aplicacionsonidospeliculas/database/aplicacionsonidospeliculas/data)) .

¿Alguien sabría donde puedo estar fallando?.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema...pudiste solucionarlo?